# automate react application using robot framework

Tags: reactjs, robotframework

Does Robot Framework support automating a web application built completely on react or not? I was trying to look for the answer in internet but unfortunately could not find one.

We have been using ROBOT framework from past 2.5 years and through this amazing tool have already automated more than 2000 scenarios but our Client's application is going to be build on React so need to have answer before selecting any other tool.

We have restricted environment where we can't open any other application so can't do POC with any open application already built on React.

Comment: Can you explain what you're tried thusfar? Mearly using Google the first result is: https://github.com/kitconcept/robotframework-react.

Comment: You're still testing a web page, whether that page is created with react or with some other tool. My team writes apps with react and we can test them just fine.

Comment: Ditto for Bryan Oakley's comment - whatever the framework is, at the end it's a web page loaded as a DOM. I'm also working on a react app, SPA mostly, and there are no issues worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks so much Bryan & Todor for sharing your confirmation and your experience. I was also under the same impression that ideally it should work. Could you please help me in one more thing, are you using selenium, selenium2 or extendedselenium2 library? Thanks Kootstra too!!

Comment: SeleniumLibrary http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html - that's the successor/the new name of selenium2

Comment: Thanks so much Todor for this help and once again many thanks to all of you.